# Using LAG to obtain multiple columns from previous rows

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following table of persons who send postcards from the city they are in at a given date. If they move to another city, they can specify how they travel, but the transportation column is not always filled.
Example: John travels from London to Berlin by plane, sends 3 postcards from Berlin and then travels to Rome by an unknown travelmethod.

```
 |Person | City    |Transport| date   |
----------------------------------------
 John   | London  | Plane   | 2016-01-10
 John   | Berlin  | NULL    | 2016-01-11
 Maria  | Berlin  | Plane   | 2016-01-14
 John   | Berlin  | NULL    | 2016-01-14
 John   | Berlin  | NULL    | 2016-01-15
 John   | Rome    | NULL    | 2016-01-17
 Maria  | London  | NULL    | 2016-01-18
 Maria  | London  | Train   | 2016-01-19
 John   | Rome    | NULL    | 2016-01-20
 Maria  | Paris   | NULL    | 2016-01-21
```

What I need is the following table, in which the data is added to each row in which city the person was previously to the current one and how she travelled to the current city.

```
 Person | City    |Transport|  date   | Prev City| Used Trans| 
------------------------------------------------------------
 John   | London  | Plane   | 16-01-10 | NULL   | NULL    |
 John   | Berlin  | NULL    | 16-01-11 | London | Plane   |
 Maria  | Berlin  | Plane   | 16-01-14 | NULL   | NULL    |
 John   | Berlin  | NULL    | 16-01-14 | London | Plane   |
 John   | Berlin  | NULL    | 16-01-15 | London | Plane   |
 John   | Rome    | NULL    | 16-01-17 | Berlin | NULL    |
 Maria  | London  | NULL    | 16-01-18 | Berlin | Plane   |
 Maria  | London  | Train   | 16-01-19 | Berlin | Plane   |
 John   | Rome    | NULL    | 16-01-20 | Berlin | NULL    |
 Maria  | Paris   | NULL    | 16-01-21 | Berlin | Train   |
```

How can this be achieved with (Teradata) SQL ?
I assume the LEAD/LAG functionality could be helpful. But I am not quite sure how to solve the problem. In particular, the LAG function only returns one previous column, but I need two.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: No reason why you can't use the LAG function twice (with the same windowing expressions) in the same SELECT list as long as the ordering is deterministic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want `lag(ignore nulls)`.  Happily, Teradata is one of the databases that supports this standard functionality:

```
select Person, City, Transport, date,
       lag(city ignore nulls) over (partition by person order by date) as prev_city,
       lag(transport ignore nulls) over (partition by person order by date) as prev_transport
from t;
```

EDIT:

Oh, I see that is not exactly the problem you have.  You can still do this entirely with window functions.  The idea is to isolate where the person changes cities.  This gives the values of the previous city and transport.

Then identify groups of rows for a given visit to the city, by doing a cumulative sum of where the cities change (this is constant for the adjacent rows within a city).

Then, `max()` spreads the previous values through all rows for the city.

```
select Person, City, Transport, date,
       max(prev_city) over (partition by person, grouping) as prev_city,
       max(prev_transport) over (partition by person, grouping) as prev_transport
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_city = city then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by user order by date) as grouping
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(city) over (partition by person order by date) as prev_city,
                   lag(transport) over (partition by person order by date) as prev_transport
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

untested, because have no teradata dbms

```
with

grouped as (
    select
        person,
        city,
        transport,
        date,
        sum(case
                when city = prev_city
                then 0
                else 1
            end) over(  partition by
                            person
                        order by
                            date) as new_city_group
    from
        (   select
                person,
                city,
                transport,
                date,
                lag(city) over( partition by
                                    person
                                order by
                                    date) as prev_city
            from
                <table_name>)
)

select
    x.*,
    y.city as prev_city,
    y.transport as prev_transport
from
    <table_name> as x
    left join ( select
                    person,
                    city,
                    max(transport) as transport,
                    max(date) as last_day_in_city,
                    lead(max(date)) over(   partition by
                                                person
                                            order by
                                                max(date)) as lead_date
                from
                    grouped
                group by
                    1, 2, new_city_group) as y on   x.person = y.person
                                                    and x.city != y.city
                                                    and x.date >= y.last_day_in_city
                                                    and x.date <= y.lead_date
order by
    4, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In Teradata DBMS there is (afaik) no lad or lag. But your task can be accomplished easly by ordered analytical functions:

```
select person, city, transport, date
,   max(city) over(partition by person order by date rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_city
,   max(transport) over(partition by person order by date rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as used_transport
from persons
```

Comment: `LAG/LEAD` exist since TD16.10 :-)